# Proper way of exposing traefik running in a on premise kubernetes cluster?

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I have an on premise Kubernetes cluster. I have traefik running in the cluster as per the example given by traefik. It is tied to a node, which will be my loadbalancer. I can access the service running(with ingress) by hitting the node port with the route. For example http://build.mydomain.com:NODEPORT will route me to my Jenkins.

But I want to be able to hit my Jenkins by simply entering http://build.mydomain.com

Is this possible or do I have to run traefik **outside** of the cluster?

Basically I just want everything hitting 80 on the load balancer to hit the traefik ingress controller, which should rout the request based on the ingresses.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: traefik
        name: traefik-ingress-lb
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
        args:
        - --api
        - --kubernetes
        - --logLevel=INFO
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/worker: loadbalancer
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-service
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: web
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      name: admin
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Basically I ended up running traefik *outside* the cluster and having it point kubernetes api-server on the master node. Then it picked up the ingress's and would route to the proper service.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy traefik inside the cluster then it can only be exposed as a service with NodePort/LoadBalancer or Ingress. If it is an Ingress, guess what you need a loadbalancer outside the cluster.

I just wanted a simple reverse proxy to discover and route traffic to new services. This worked well by up running traefik outside the cluster and having it **point kubernetes api-server** on the master node. This is done in the Traefik config file. Like this:

```
[kubernetes]
endpoint = "https://my-master-node:6443"
token="" <-- GET THIS FROM YOUR KUBERNETES MASTER NODE
certAuthFilePath = "/root/ssl/ca.crt" <-- GET THIS FROM YOUR KUBERNETES MASTER NODE
```

Then it picked up the ingress's and would route to the proper service.

One of the services I was configuring in my cluster was Jenkins. Jenkins expects it's agents to connect on port 50000 by default. I spent some time trying to figure out how to get a rout based on the same host to hit another port in cluster. Couldn't really get it working.

Then I found out that trafik doesn't support TCP. Jenkins agents contact the master over http to say hello and **then** set up the agent to slave connection over **TCP**.

So in the end wasted effort :-(